# Can embedded UIController height constraints transcend embedding?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, ios11

I have the following configuration for an iOS app:

[image]

A container view is constrained against it's parent UIViewController's view:

- center horizontally
- equal widths
- equal bottoms

The embedded sub view controller has a single full view that is constrained with the following:

- center horizontally
- center vertically
- equal widths
- equal height
- constant height = 200

At this point the subview controller should create a view that wants to be 200 high and as wide as the screen. But the container view is flagged as needing a height or y position.

Is there a way to get the the constrains of the embedded view to couple into the embedding set?

#### UPDATE

I can use the `viewDidLayoutSubview()` hook in the main UIViewController to get things sized correctly, kind of. The following works:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let subSize = self.subController.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
    self.containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: subSize).isActive = true
}
```

But if it can do that, I would think that the following should work too:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.subController.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

But this second just ends up with zero height.

Comment: The container needs a height constraint because it does not know it’s intrinsic content size. The embedded view controller can not communicate this.  You would be better off deleting the height constraint on the embedded controller

Comment: You could set up a delegate to send the value needed up to the main controller to adjust at run time but no the intrinsic size is not passed up the chain